# Parse.com Integration gives Bad request error

Tags: c#, api, rest, curl, parse-platform

In my web Admin, i have to integrate the Parse.com push notification to send  the push notifications to subscribers.

My question is

> Do i need to integrate REST APIs with curl in my asp.net admin? or
>   there is any other standard C# SDK to implement?

If answer is REST Api then documentation for integrating with the REST api has following example.

> curl -X POST \
>
> -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: " \
>
> -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " \
>
> -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>
> -d '{"score":1337}' \
>
> https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore

I have started to integrate the REST API by setting up a test console application to test the urls. The application i developed has following code.

```
    class Program
{
    private const string URL = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore";
    private const string DATA = @"{""score"":1337";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program.CreateObject();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void CreateObject()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", "My Application ID given in example");
        request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "the api key given in example");
        request.ContentLength = DATA.Length;
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        requestWriter.Write(DATA);
        requestWriter.Close();

        try
        {
            WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
            Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
            string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.Out.WriteLine(response);
            responseReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("-----------------");
            Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The code gives a **400 Bad request error**

I don't understand what i am missing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATA is missing a closing brace.